# Nautlius script with while only 2 iterations

Tags: 16.04, bash, scripts, nautilus

I'm kinda new to this. My nautilus script only seems to extract the first two archives when using the following code:

```
echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | while read file
    do
        mkdir "${file%.*}"
        unzip -o -d "${file%.*}" "$file" || unrar e "$file" "${file%.*}"

done
```

I'm trying to extract a lot of archives. Each into it's own subfolder. It just stops after two archives. If I select the rest of the archives it will again do only two...

Comment: Looks fine, maybe it's related to IFS, put `IFS=` in the first line of your script see whats happens.

Comment: Nope. Changed nothing

Comment: It should be `while IFS= read -r file`.  Try that. How many archives you're extracting ? Do any of them contain special character or spaces or tabs in filename ?

Comment: They do have spaces in them. I tried that line and it worked. thx!